# Finitely presentable objects and the Kleisli category

Tags: category-theory, monads, locally-presentable-categories

There is a correspendence between Lawvere theories $L$ and finitary monads $\mathbb{T}_L$ (associated to $L$), due to Lawvere: the category $Mod(L)$ of models of $L$ (in $\mathbf{Set}$) is equivalent to the Eilenberg-Moore category $\mathbb{T}_L$-$\mathbf{Alg}$ of algebras over the monad $\mathbb{T}_L$.

Now, this category $\mathbb{C}=Mod(L)$ is a locally finitely presentable category (by definition). Write $\mathbb{C}_f$ for the (full) subcategory of finitely presentable objects of $\mathbb{C}$. Can $\mathbb{C}_f$ be constructed somehow from the Kleisli category $\mathbf{Kl}(\mathbb{T}_L)$ of the monad $\mathbb{T}_L$? It seems to me that there must be some relationship between the two (at first I thought $\mathbb{C}_f=\mathbf{Kl}(\mathbb{T}_L)^{\text{op}}$, but this is definitely not the case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin Carlson is right, of course. But you can construct the category of finitely presentable algebras as the free reflexive coequalizer completion of the Lawvere theory itself, though. See [Theorem 7.3](http://www.iti.cs.tu-bs.de/~adamek/algebraic_theories.pdf#page=68) in Adámek, Rosický, and Vitale's *Algebraic Theories*.

You can also distinguish the free algebras $A$ which are finitely presentable in $\mathbb{T}_L-\mathbf{Alg}$ from those which are not by the fact that $\mathbf{KL}(\mathbb{T}_L)(A,-)$ commutes with the filtered colimit $B \to 2\cdot B \to \dots \to \omega \cdot B \to \dots \to \kappa \cdot $ for every infinite $\kappa$, where $B$ is any object of $\mathbf{KL}(\mathbb{T}_L)$ and $\alpha \cdot B$ is the $\alpha$-fold coproduct of $B$ with itself.

Putting these together, you can pass from $\mathbf{KL}(\mathbb{T}_L)$ to its finite rank objects to their reflexive coequalizer completion. Of course, you could also just construct $\mathbb{T}_L-\mathbf{Alg}$ from $\mathbf{KL}(\mathbb{T}_L)$ (I think it's also a reflexive coequalizer completion) and then just take the finitely presentable objects in the resulting category.

Comment: Thanks! Just a clarification, $L$ (the Lawvere theory) is actually $(\mathbf{Kl}(\mathbb{T}_L)_f)^{\text{op}}$ always, right? (the category opposite to the full subcategory of finitely presentable objects of the Kleisli category). I think I am getting confused over that too now..

Comment: Right. It's kind of confusing. Personally, I tend to think of $L^\mathrm{op} = \mathbf{Kl}(\mathbb{T}_L)$ as the "primary object".

Comment: $L^{\text{op}}$ is the whole of Kleisli, not its finitely presentable objects?

Comment: Oh, that was silly of me, of course not. $L^\mathrm{op}$ is just the finitely presentable objects of the Kleisli category.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no relation. The Kleisli category is the category of free algebras, for instance, of all free groups. It has nothing to do with finiteness.

Answer (score 1):

This question has a much more satisfactory answer using the theory of [relative monads](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relative+monad), since this allows us to relate freeness to finiteness (which is not possible using ordinary monads, as pointed out by Kevin Arlin). A Lawvere theory is precisely the Kleisli inclusion of a ($\mathbf{FinSet} \to \mathbf{Set}$)-relative monad $T$ (e.g. see Chapter 3 of [Monadic and Higher-Order Structure](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/handle/1810/338940)). Its category of algebras is the cocompletion of the Kleisli category of $T$ under [sifted colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sifted+colimit) (equivalently under [filtered colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/filtered+limit)). The subcategory of (strongly) finitely presentable objects is therefore given by the [Cauchy completion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy%20complete%20category) of the Kleisli category.